# Material Design data table filtering

Tags: gui-design, filter, data-tables, material-design

How would you implement filtering in MD data table? Sorting, paging and searching is obvious but I need more complex filtering.

Should I put the filters on the table title or create a separate filtering section on top of the table (using cards for each filter for example)?

What I'd like is something like this: https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/38533/78885

[image]

Comment: I ended up doing it with [dropdowns and inputs](http://i.snag.gy/mnNYu.jpg).

Answer (score 10):

If you need complex filter consider creating a separate section. Perhaps a "actions" section on top of the table where users can not just filter but perform other actions to interact or modify the table.

Here is how [Airtable](http://airtable.com) does filter for complex spreadsheets. Some visual design improvements could be done, though.

[image]

Here is another example, from [Toggl](http://toggl.com). Although it's not a data table it's the same concept of filtering data.

[image]

Your approach with dropdowns and inputs are essentially the same and seems pretty good.